# how hadoop handle ram when execute query?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

in Relation-database model like mysql , when user send query to database like "SELECT message.message_id FROM message" whole table 'message' loading in RAM . when tables are very large and server hasn't enough memory, mysql crashed.
sorry about my question . i have no idea how describe my question . my database course in university ask search about how hadoop handle tables and query when query send to database and hadoop tries to execute query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework I won't fully answer your question, but I will point you in the right direction.  In a traditional relational database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite) all the processing for a single query is done on a single machine.  Even with [replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_%28computing%29#Database_replication), one query runs on one machine.

[Hadoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) uses a [distributed filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#HDFS) to spread the work across multiple machines.  Using [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce), one query can be broken up into smaller pieces and performed in parallel on multiple machines.

This *can* be faster, it depends on your data and your queries.  What it really buys you is the ability to scale to handle more and more data and more and more queries.  Rather than having to buy more powerful and more expensive database servers (even with replication, your database hardware has to be beefy), you can add inexpensive machines to your Hadoop cluster.

As for this...

> > when user send query to database like "SELECT message.message_id FROM message" whole table 'message' loading in RAM. when tables are very large and server hasn't enough memory, mysql crashed

This assumption is wrong. The whole table is not loaded into MySQL memory (unless MySQL is even dumber than I give it credit for). The database will read the table row-by-row.  Just like if you open a huge file, it's still read line-by-line. Even with an ORDER BY, the sorting will be done on disk.

I suspect your teacher is trying to emphasize the advantages of a distributed database, and being able to deal with enormous datasets is one of them, but MySQL will not crash just because you query a large table.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike sql queries, in hadoop you need to write map reduce job to extract the data. Now a days, there are many wrappers are available on top of map reduce job such as hive, pig, phoenix, etc.

In these wrapper you can run sql like queries, but at the end, it will convert queries into map reduce job, and it will return output looking like sql query result. It is calld SQL on NoSQL.

If FileSystem and MapReduce are installed on a node, MapR allocates 20% of physical memory to FileSystem, about 5-8% of memory for OS and other applications and the rest would be given to MapReduce services

On an average about 75% of physical memory is assigned to MapReduce in this kind of setting. Note that for the mfs process MapR pre-allocates 20% of memory, which means mfs grabs 20% of memory immediately. On the other hand, MapReduce services starts off low and eventually grows up to 75% of physical memory because memory is not pre-allocated when you configure and start TaskTracker service.

For more detail, check below link:

https://www.mapr.com/developercentral/code/memory-management-basics#.VTEoVq2qqko